# Get only one relation by id

Tags: laravel

The model has a hasMany connection - properties.

How can I get not everything at once, namely one property by its ID (single property id)?

I'm trying to do something like this, I end up with an empty `single_properties` array.

```
$companyList = Company::with(['single_properties' => function($query) use($coordsPropId) {
        $query->where('id', $coordsPropId->id);
    }])
    ->where([
        ['is_hidden', false],
    ])
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

HasMany:

```
public function single_properties(): hasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(CompanySingleProps::class);
}
```

Comment: can you show Company model code .

Comment: Very big code in Company model :)

Comment: hasMany works fine, but i need not all properties, only one

Comment: my bad, need to use `$query->where('prop_id', $coordsPropId->id);`